# createListenerMiddleware to trigger when extraReducer has job done?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have a Redux `createListenerMiddleware` defined in `store.ts`:

```
export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: myAction,
    effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
      //  do job
    }
})
```

Then `myAction` action is defined in seprate `MyAction-slice.ts` as follows:

```
const applicationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'app',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        myAction(state) {
            // do pure functional code here
        },
    }
})
```

And it works fine when I call `myAction` from a React component (first `myAction` did its job, then `createListenerMiddleware` for that particular action has been fired, e.g:

```
return (
    <>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(myAction())}>
    </>
)
```

However I also have a `createAsyncThunk` defined in `MyAction-slice.ts` as follows:

```
export const myAsyncAction = createAsyncThunk(
    'app/async',
    async () => {
        const promiseData = await axios.get(`https://localhost:8888/hello`)
        // handle errors for promiseData
        return promiseData
    }
)
```

And then I declare that `thunk` inside `createSlice` as follows:

```
...
extraReducers: (builder) => {
     builder
        .addCase(myAsyncAction.fulfilled, (state, payload) => {
            // change state with a pure functional way
        })
...
```

And also at the end of my `MyAction-slice.ts` file I export actions as:

```
export const {myAction} = applicationSlice.actions
```

My problem is that I wish to somehow "hook" to `myAsyncAction.fulfilled` reducer using `createListenerMiddleware`, the same way I did for `myAction` reducer. Is it even possible?

Comment: I would suggest replacing redux-thunk with redux-saga if you want to do this.

Comment: @DavidBradshaw won't do that, since official Redux docs advise not to use Saga /Observable and stick to Redux. I hope that it is possible with createMiddlewareListener, but I just yet have not enough knowledge on that

Comment: Redux-toolkit was written by someone completely different to Redux and has some very strange opinions in it. In my experience you are better off avoiding opinionated tools, as eventually you end up in a situation like this, where you need to do something differently. Then you end up fighting against the opinionated tool trying to make it do something, that would be very easy to do in the base library.

Comment: Actually looking at your question a bit more, if you’re happy to ignore the toolkit and write a custom middleware, then this can be done in three lines of code. You just have to call `next(action)`  in  the first line , rather than the last.  When you do this, you then  have access to the updated store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `myAsyncAction.fulfilled` is also an `ActionCreator`.

Add that to your `MyAction-slice.ts` after `createAsyncThunk`:

```
export const myAsyncActionCreator = myAsyncAction.fulfilled as AsyncThunkFulfilledActionCreator<AxiosResponse<any, any>, AsyncThunkConfig>
```

Also replace `myAsyncAction.fulfilled` to `myAsyncActionCreator` in your `extraReducers`.

Then your `createListenerMiddleware` would look like (`store.ts`):

```
export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: myAsyncActionCreator,
    effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
      //  do job
    }
})
```

Also don't forget to `prepend` this listener to your `configureStore` right after your reducers list:

```
export const store = configureStore({
reducer: {...}
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware),
})
```

Following same idea, you could also create `myAsyncAction.rejected` action creator and export it in a same manner and use as:

```
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: myAsyncActionCreatorRejected
```